# Laravel eloquent "belongsTo" / "hasOne"

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have given an **existing** database with two tables:

```
customers (address_id)
addresses
```

Further, each customer in customers has an AddressID. Normally, I would assume that each address has an id of the customer, but here the customer has the address id.

Now I'm looking for a model function to retrieve the address from the customer to use something like `{{ $customer->address }}` in the blade template:

e.g. Customer.php

```
public function address() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Address', 'CustomerID', 'AddressID');
}
```

q: how to fetch the related address for the customer?

// Edit: it is an existing table with data I can currently not update.

My work around was:

```
$customer->address = Address::find($customer->AddressID);
```

Comment: what problem you are facing now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters in your `belongsTo` call are just a bit wrong. Try this:

```
$this->belongsTo('Address', 'AddressID');
                                 ^
                            foreign key
```

You can omit the 3rd argument as long as the `$primaryKey` property on the `Address` model is set (or it's the conventional `id`)

Comment: Awesome, this small hint did it! <3

Answer (score 1):

In customer model create function like this

```
public function address() {
    return $this->hasOne('Address', 'CustomerID', 'AddressID');
}
```

Where `Address` is name of address model `CustomerID` is primary key in `customers` (I recommend use just `id`) and `AddressID` is reference to `Address` in customers table. So, now you can use `{{ $customer->address }}` which will retrieve customer`s address.

Comment: Yes, I thought something like this. But the address has no customer id.